# C: HTTP header parsing

Tags: c, http

I need to parse the header to extract the absolute URL from the http request.
The Method that I only care about are only GET, POST and HEAD. I would like to confirm that the following simple logic/pseudo code would be sufficient enough to cover most of the cases,

```
1  url = extract the url from the first request line;
2  if (url[0] == '/') {
3    //relative url, keep reading until HOST or end of the header
4    while (nextline != "\r\n\r\n") {
5      if (nextline starts with HOST) {
6         host = extract the host value;
7         return (host+url);
8      } else {
9         continue;
10     }
11     
12   }
13    return bad_req;
14 } else {
15   //absolute url, return directly, ignore HOST
16    return url;
17 }
```

1) are there any cases left out?

2) is line 2 enough to tell whether it's a relative URL or an absolute URL?

3) do encodings matter?

4) other possible glitches?

btw, performance is a very important factor that I need to consider.

Comment: You can do this algorithm more common, for example [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ccgilib/) is my CGI library.

Answer (score 0):

nextline != "\r\n\r\n" <---- this does not work in C

Try while ( strcmp (nextline, "\r\n\r\n") == 0 )

> if (nextline starts with HOST)

if ( strncmp(nextline, "http://www.frogs.com", strlen(nextline)) == 0)

== 0 means matches.  If doesn't match, result is less than or greater than 0.  Above line depends on string length of nextline being >= string length of "http://www.frogs.com".

"btw, performance is a very important factor that I need to consider."

C has bare metal performance = "light speed".  It would take a tremendous amount of skill to both write low performance C code and also have a competency level high enough to write C code that compiles without warnings and also doesn't crash.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. it was only meant to be pseudo code. I am more worried about if I have some corner cases left out, for example, "weird" HTTP headers, encodings, etc. things like that.